# fill checkedlistbox items based on selected items of another checkedlistbox in vb.net sql server

Tags: vb.net

Plz Help

I am using Visual Studio 2017, sql server 2016
My requirement is to fill checkedlistbox2 based on selected item of checkedlistbox1
and if unchecked then only remove its related item not all

suppose

Checkedlistbox1(contains Department)(fill all departments from sql) , checkedlistbox2 (Sub Department) fill only selected values from CheckedListBox1, if uncheck from checkedlistbox1 then remove
open third Checkedlistbox3 with Sub department item(get only checked values from Checkedlistbox2)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of binding parent and child `DataTables` to two `CheckedListBoxes` and filtering the second list based on the items checked in the first:

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim parentTable As New DataTable

    With parentTable.Columns
        .Add("ParentId", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("ParentName", GetType(String))
    End With

    With parentTable.Rows
        .Add(1, "Parent1")
        .Add(2, "Parent2")
        .Add(3, "Parent3")
    End With

    BindingSource1.DataSource = parentTable

    With CheckedListBox1
        .DataSource = BindingSource1
        .DisplayMember = "ParentName"
        .ValueMember = "ParentId"
    End With

    Dim childTable As New DataTable

    With childTable.Columns
        .Add("ChildId", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("ParentId", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("ChildName", GetType(String))
    End With

    With childTable.Rows
        .Add(1, 1, "Child1A")
        .Add(2, 1, "Child1B")
        .Add(3, 1, "Child1C")
        .Add(4, 2, "Child2A")
        .Add(5, 2, "Child2B")
        .Add(6, 2, "Child2C")
        .Add(7, 3, "Child3A")
        .Add(8, 3, "Child3B")
        .Add(9, 3, "Child3C")
    End With

    BindingSource2.DataSource = childTable
    BindingSource2.Filter = "ParentId = 0"

    With CheckedListBox2
        .DataSource = BindingSource2
        .DisplayMember = "ChildName"
        .ValueMember = "ChildId"
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck
    Dim checkedItems = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Cast(Of DataRowView).ToList()
    Dim currentItem = DirectCast(CheckedListBox1.Items(e.Index), DataRowView)

    If e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked Then
        checkedItems.Add(currentItem)
    Else
        checkedItems.Remove(currentItem)
    End If

    If checkedItems.Any() Then
        BindingSource2.Filter = $"ParentId IN ({String.Join(", ", checkedItems.Select(Function(drv) drv.Row.Field(Of Integer)("ParentId")))})"
    Else
        BindingSource2.Filter = "ParentId = 0"
    End If
End Sub
```

The `ItemCheck` event occurs before the state of the item changes, which is why the current item has to be either added or removed from the list of checked items. The `"ParentId = 0"` filter is used to ensure that no children match the filter if no parents are checked.

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to approach this would be to bind Checkedlistbox1 on Pageload inside a Not Me.IsPostBack. Then using SelectedIndexChanged for Checkedlistbox1 bind Checkedlistbox2, this can then be repeated for the SelectedIndexChanged on Checkedlistbox2 for Checkedlistbox3.

For the example below I've just added the item value to a list of integers which you can then pass to your sql parameters for your Checkedlistbox2 & 3 bindings.

```
    Private Sub Checkedlistbox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Checkedlistbox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim cb2 As List(Of Integer) = (New List(Of Integer))
    For Each item As ListItem In Checkedlistbox1.Items
        If item.Selected Then
            cb2.Add(item.Value)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The `CheckedListBox` is a WinForms control. You're talking about Web Forms, so you must be thinking of the `CheckBoxList` control.

Comment: Apologies, an oversight. Would the same thing be achievable with ItemCheck?

Comment: Not getting the desired result, so sorry