# Fill datagridview based on another datagridview checked values vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Pls help

On form load already my Datagridview1 is populated with checkboxcolumn,
My requirement is to fill another Datagridview2 based on checked or selected values from Datgridview1
pls help in coding
how to code
which event is to called
Pls help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you piece together a solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69224577/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69257259/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69481949/ ?

Comment: Don't fall into the trap of iterating through rows on you DVG.  You DGV should be bound to some Data collection object like a DataTable, you're far better off doing any sort of data manipulation direct on the data objects themselves rather than the overheads of UI

Comment: How is DataGridView1 populated. Please include the code as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

So, in my understanding what you need is when you click on one of the checkboxes inside the grid be able to retrieve the row number, the column number and if it's checked or not, with this you know exactly where the user clicked and can perform tasks on the other grid. If it's just a simple DataGridView (no data from a database) you can use like this:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    Dim bChecked As Boolean
    Dim cx As DataGridViewCell = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex)
    bChecked = cx.GetEditedFormattedValue(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex)
    MsgBox("Row: " & e.RowIndex & " - Col: " & e.ColumnIndex & " - Value: " & bChecked.ToString())
End Sub
```